# Android code pin view without 10 listener

Tags: android, view

I'm making a View with 12 button
from 0 to 9 and an OK and a CE one

I'm trying to make a view who aske user a code PIN But with this method i have 12 on clik listener... It's really an annoying code.

Have you anyway to regroupe all Btn from 0 to 9 in one listener And still be able from code to know if user input btn 0 or btn 6?

I will not past my xml here because he is too damn long...
It's a linear layout with in each ligne another linear layout
Inside every they are 4 btns 
And i use weigth to make them fit every screen... So i have also add some View with nothing to make my view with more spacing.

I have try to get the id of each view inside my on click but it's the same i have a switch of 10 case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1: Create a `HashMap` assigning button id (as key) to the value.

Option 2 (not so recommended): Ask the `Button` for its text (the digit as a string) and process it further

Comment: Why option 2 is not recommended?

Comment: @Jebik Only for the rare case that a language may use other digit characters than the usual ones. Apart from this corner case it is ok.

Comment: This work and i have find something else the android:tag i have use it instead of text so my listener look like this now


     `@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    text.setText(text.getText() + "*");
    code += v.getTag();
    }`

I use the tag and add it to actual code and add a "\*" to make something visible to user



Is this better than Text usage or not?